# Проблема с написанием команд telebot python Telegram. /ban

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, chat

Всем здравствуйте, я пишу бота на telegram, на библиотеке telebot. Делаю бота для группы. Сначала сделал удаление сообщений, в случае обнаружения нецензурной лексики, но, сами понимаете, обнаружить нецензурные выражения не так-то просто в наше время, когда русскую б могут заменить на 6(шесть(один и тот же символ, согласитесь)). Поэтому решил создать команду по типу **/ban**. В самой команде нет проблем, а вот в её реализации есть проблемы. Помогите написать код, чтобы на сообщение /ban модератора (это сообщение будет ответом модератора на сообщение другого "плохого" пользователя) бот отвечал **изгнанием из группы** "плохого" человека и не давал ему возможности зайти по его id. Сам бот тоже **является** модератором группы. Возможно ли это вообще сделать с библиотекой telebot?

Comment: Это эта библиотека? https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot

Comment: Да, это та самая библиотека